# .click event inside .click event is not working properly

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am new to Javascript and i faced issue when i trying to do "nested" .click event.
I had several btnA,btnB,btnC.
So i wanna check if

> "#btnA" + $('form .countryWrapperBorder input') clicked{
>
> alert("A")
> }

> "#btnB" + $('form .countryWrapperBorder input') clicked{
>
> alert("B")
> }

```
  $("#btnA").click(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();

    $('form .countryWrapperBorder input').one('click', function(e) {
        alert("a");
    //problems goes into here. When i click "#btnB or btnA", it goes into this condition (meaning looping happened
    });
});

 $("#btnB").click(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();

    $('form .countryWrapperBorder input').one('click', function(e) {
        alert("b");
    //problems goes into here. When i click "#btnB or btnA", it goes into this condition (meaning looping happened
    });
});
```

The question: **How can i go into alert("b") condition only if "#btnB" is clicked. I dont wan go to into alert("b") scenario when "#btnA" is clicked.**
Thanks alot

Comment: share the html form

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if this solves the issue, as not sure of your usecase . but you can do by setting a variable. Something like below. I did not ran this code, the code is just for idea

```
var clickedId;
 $("#btnA").click(function() {
clickedId = "btnA"
    
});

 $("#btnB").click(function() {
clickedId = "btnB"
    
});

$('form .countryWrapperBorder input').one('click', function(e) {
     if( clickedId == "btnA" )
        alert("a");
     else if( clickedId == "btnB" )   
          alert("b");
    //problems goes into here. When i click "#btnB or btnA", it goes into this condition (meaning looping happened
    });
```

If you want to do your way. Here is something which should work

```js
$("#btnA").click(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
$('form.countryWrapperBorder input').off('click');
    $('form.countryWrapperBorder input').on('click', function(e) {
        alert("a");
    //problems goes into here. When i click "#btnB or btnA", it goes into this condition (meaning looping happened
    });
});

 $("#btnB").click(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
$('form.countryWrapperBorder input').off('click');
    $('form.countryWrapperBorder input').on('click', function(e) {
        alert("b");
    //problems goes into here. When i click "#btnB or btnA", it goes into this condition (meaning looping happened
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form class="countryWrapperBorder">
  <input type="text"/>
</form>

<button id="btnA" >btnA</button>
<button id="btnB">btnB</button>
```

Comment: Could you explain why that scenario will happen if im using my code? By right should trigger alert("a) if and only i click "#btnA". why will it happen too when i clicked "btnB"

Comment: so first of all using your code if you click btnA the click event will fire and that will register one event for tine input inside form, but will not fire, it will just register the event, again when you click btnB that will register another event. One thing you can do is to delete the event before you add again, look into jquery "off". But not sure you need to compilate this.

Comment: Check my update above. I have added the code as per your logic which will work.

Answer (score 0):

Can you describe the problem a bit more clearly?

In my opinion, you should be like this:

```js
$("#btnA").click(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();

    $('form .countryWrapperBorder input').one('click', function(e) {
        //alert("a");
    //problems goes into here. When i click "#btnB or btnA", it goes into this condition (meaning looping happened
    });
});

 $("#btnB").click(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();

    $('form .countryWrapperBorder input').one('click', function(e) {
        alert("b");
    //problems goes into here. When i click "#btnB or btnA", it goes into this condition (meaning looping happened
    });
});
```

Comment: Hi, I try this as well.

Comment: My problem is when i click on $('form .countryWrapperBorder input') , no matter its btnA /btnB is clicked. it will go into this condition. meaning everything  $('form .countryWrapperBorder input') is clicked. i will get alert(a) and alert(b)